# Create user contact form that feeds a mysql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have zero experience creating websites. I do not know PHP. My goal is to create a website landing page that has a user contact form that collects simple fields such as name, email, etc., from site visitors. My question is specifically regarding the form.

Is there a Wordpress plug-in that creates a front-end user contact form and feeds that input data directly into a database (I use MySQL)?

Comment: contact form 7 with this extension might work for you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/

Comment: FYI - MySQL Workbench is just a GUI for managing a MySQL database. Your actual RDMS is MySQL.

Comment: @Azer it looks like that just saves it to the Wordpress site? I would need it to save it directly into a MySQL database...

Comment: The WordPress database is a MySQL database, so you can access any data in the WordPress DB with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @Azer How do I access the Contact Form 7 database (in Wordpress) from Workbench? I'm a novice...

Comment: I have never tried accessing CF7 forms specifically, but if you look in the wp-config.php file in the root folder of the WordPress website, you can find the connection information to the WordPress database. Location, Username, Password etc. You can use the same information in MySQL Workbench to connect to the database.

Comment: Just a sidenote. The server might be set up to refuse remote connections directly to the database. In that case you will need to ask whoever runs your server (if you're not doing it yourself) to allow connections from the IP you will use workbench from.